# Turn off the 'Article title' header in sn-jnl.cls file

Tags: header-footer, springernature, cls

I want the 'Article Title' to not appear in the header of every page in my springer-nature latex document. May I know what to comment out / replace in the sn-jnl.cls file? Thanks.

Comment: Why? Usually journal classes are used, because of publishing in the journal. In this case, every change of the class should be avoided. The publisher will not use your changed class and usually does not want you to change anything. However, there is a `\markboth` in the definition of `\title`. Using `\markboth{}{}` *after* the title should remove the title from the page headings. Because of the missing [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), this is only a comment and I've not tested it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.